# Is there a way to get the cursor position in a mfc application?

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I'm using the OnKeyDown handler to detect for an Enter key press:

```
void CShortestPathFinderView::OnKeyDown(UINT nChar, UINT nRepCnt, UINT nFlags)
{
  if( nChar == VK_RETURN)    //Enter key is pressed
{
    CClientDC aDC(this);
    rubberbanding = 0;
            m_pTempElement->vertices[i++]=  /*cursor position??*/;
    mSecondPoint=m_pTempElement->vertices[0];
    m_pTempElement->Draw(&aDC);
}
```

In the 3rd line of the if statement I need to store the cursor position in an array, but how do I acquire that point? Does the handler provide me with it? or is there a separate function to do so?

Comment: @Jerry Coffin  There- I've edited it. Thanks for pointing that out, I didn't realize how ambiguous it was.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the current cursor position, you can call `GetCursorPos`. I don't believe MFC provides a wrapper for this, so it'll just be the Win32 [`::GetCursorPos`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648390.aspx). It returns the point in screen coordinates, so you'll (almost certainly) want to use [`ScreenToClient`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162952.aspx) to convert that to client area coordinates before storing it.

Note, however, that `GetCursorPos` will return the position of the cursor *when you call it*. That may or may not be quite the same as the position the cursor was at when the key was pressed (though it *will* normally be at least quite close).

Usually, to add a cursor position like this, you'd want to react to the user clicking the mouse button (e.g., [`WM_LBUTTONDOWN`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645607.aspx)). That message will tell you the position of the mouse when the button was clicked.